# Pourquoi dit-on « rien ne sert de courir » ?

Tags: expressions, usage

Tout le monde ou presque connait l'expression suivante :

> Rien ne sert de courir, il suffit de partir à point.

Pourtant le premier bout de la phrase (« rien ne sert de courir ») me parait être en français incorrect. Ne devrait-on pas dire « il ne sert à rien de courir » ?

Si ce bout de phrase est correct, quelle est l'origine de ce « rien » en tant que sujet ?

Comment: À l'oral, je pense qu'on utiliserait plutôt : « Cela ne sert à rien de courir », plutôt, afin de garder un certain genre « neutre ».

Comment: @Larme Dans « Il ne sert à rien de... », « Il » est complètement neutre et impersonnel, de la même façon que l'on utilise ce pronom pour dire « Il pleut. » Cependant, je suis d'accord avec toi sur le fait que l'on utiliserait plus volontairement « cela » avec _servir_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le fait qu'il s'agit d'une citation de la fable [Le Lièvre et la Tortue](http://poesie.webnet.fr/lesgrandsclassiques/poemes/jean_de_la_fontaine/le_lievre_et_la_tortue.html) (1668)
de Jean de la Fontaine en fait une locution figée, mais le tour d'utiliser rien comme sujet existe encore, plus ou moins recherché suivant le verbe. Si avec *rien ne sert...* une allusion à la fable semble inévitable, ceux-ci me semblent plus courant:

- Rien n'est plus ... que ...
- Rien ne vaut ...
- Rien ne fait plus ... que ...

Comment: Pourrais-tu m'expliquer d'où vient l'utilisation de _rien_ en tant que sujet ?

Comment: @Zistoloen, _rien_ est un pronom (comme _tout_ d'ailleurs) parfois employé substantivement (voir _un tout petit rien_) et donc **rien** ne s'oppose à ce qu'il soit un sujet (et c'est même pas fait exprès).  Ce qui est un peu plus rare -- et pas possible systématiquement -- , c'est _rien_ employé à la place d'un _il_ impersonnel pour en faire la négation.